# Are Socket.io Namespaces really a individual spaces?

Tags: socket.io, namespaces

I'm using namespaces to separate different customers. Using this code at the server side:

```
// server-side
const workspaces = io.of(/^\/\w+\/$/);
workspaces.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        workspaces.to(roomName).emit('chat message', msg)
    })
})
```

---

And on the client side (each client is a different customer):

```
// client-side - customer01
const socket = io('ws://server:3000/customer01/')

// client-side - customer02
const socket = io('ws://server:3000/customer02/')
```

However, when customer01 emits something, customer02 receives the data and vice versa. The expected shouldn't be that every namespace client receives only the data it is 'address to'?

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake on my code, the correct is this one:

```
// server-side
workspaces.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const specificWorkspace = socket.nsp;
    console.log('someone is connected @ workspace.name: ' + specificWorkspace.name)
    specificWorkspace.to(roomName).emit('chat message', msg)
})
```

The old I haven't add the `socket.nsp`, so, I was emitting to the whole socket instead of the specific one.